# how to detect animals face using iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone

I am implementing one iPhone animal application. In which I want to add face detection of animals face using iPhone sdk. I have checked OpenCV, but in that only human face detection is possible. Is it possible to detect animal face  using iOS sdk.

Please give me advice about this query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are research going on this and various paper with algorithms have been predicte. Read the following papers for animal face detection.
http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~troppel/internal/sparc/TourBot/TourBot%20References/Haar/2000186.pdf
http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/Publications/Papers/2000483.pdf